# G_sheet: Find the same title and bring to another sheet all values (under the same title)

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am building an application in google sheet for marketing purposes.

In sheet #1, I want my colleagues to copy paste their data (date, clicks, conversions, etc).

In the next sheet (#2) I am using the data to generate ideas for experiments.

The ask:
I want a formula (or script) to use in sheet#2 so I can re-position certain columns in certain order according to my needs.

Why?
In order to be able to generate these ideas, I need to have certain columns in certain order and I have 0 trust that my colleagues will use the the same reporting order (for example if conversions are not in column X, the application doesn't work).

Sheet #1  [DATA input]
Column A: Conversions
Column B: Click
Column C: Conversion rate

In Sheet #2 I want to have

Column A: Conversion rate
Column B: Conversions

I am using:

=ArrayFormula({INDEX('Sheet#1'!$A$2:$Q$997,0,MATCH(A1, 'Sheet#1'!$A$1:$Q$1, 0))})

But it doesn't work all the time.

I need something scalable so my colleagues can use as well.

Example of the Google sheet: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vRTxDAMrXQAsmZw-LtYJ5IISYjdWA9TM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand exactly what you want, but possibly the following formula pulls the data in the order you want:

```
=QUERY('IMPORT YOUR DATA'!A:C,"select B, C, A where A<>''",1)
```

In your sample sheet, you placed Clicks in column A, but your question says you want just Conversion Rate and Conversions.  If you don't want the Clicks, change the "B, C, A" portion of my equation to just "C, A".

If this is not what you want, can you manually enter the result you would like to have, given the data you have.

### Edit

When I opened your sheet as a Google Sheet, all of your data columns were text strings, even though they look like numeric values.  This may have been just a mistake on my part, but in any case, it is easy to fix, by using VALUE, if necesary.  But it did mean that I treated thee data as text strings, which meant a minor difference in the formula.

If the data was numeric values, the formula would be:

```
=QUERY('IMPORT YOUR DATA'!A:C,"select B, C, A where A > 0 ",1)
```

[image]